# Android fragments with observables. When to add vs replace other fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, observable, android-transitions, android-profiler

Another Fragment question.

For context:

- Single activity application with two fragments, Home and Settings.
- My activity immediately adds Home when the app starts.
- On this screen the user can tap a settings icon to view the Settings fragment.

It is at this point I'm unsure whether I should use [#add](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String) or [#replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction#replace) to show my Settings Fragment.

---

Let me explain why.

1. Replace

Replacing the fragment is pretty cool. It has a nice enter/exit animation for both fragments. And the lifecycle methods paused->destroy in Home are called, allowing it to remove any observables and release references that are no longer necessary since the view isn't showing anymore.

However when I push the back button to pop off Settings, Home now has to recreate itself. Since there are a few things going on and a somewhat complex list, I will get a framerate drop below 60fps for a single frame (Using the [gpu profiling tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/inspect-gpu-rendering)).  Some phones can power through this but ones like the Nexus 5 can't and have an ugly transition effect and laggy delay (maybe 500ms- 1s) before the view actually pops off after hitting the button.

2. Add

Adding the fragment is also pretty cool. It doesn't have the framerate problems when transitioning back. So it looks nice and smooth on all my test devices.

However it doesn't actually exit the view. So there isn't an exit animation. The lifecycle events to release observers aren't called either so its still modifying the view to changes it receives even though the user isn't seeing it.

---

So which is the appropriate solution for my case? Is there a conventional answer to this? Or is there something else I should be doing? Should I refactor a lot of code to optimize replacing the fragment? Or is it ok for Home to be sitting in the background listening to events?

Answer (score 0):

In case of your data needs to preserve on settings page and flow back and forth then adding a line

```
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

would be helpful but,

> if you traverse home-settings-home few more times then you will be in big trouble of back button press event. This event will be moved back in your stack till last  fragment page left.

So, for sake of simplicity, while adding a settings fragment, dont use

```
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

For replace,
(Dynamic data on home page will be erased on replace and regenerated on  added from settings or restarted an app ).
Your home page will load every time coming back from settings page and that would be bad idea.
Replace is used when the fragment page is no longer required for next operations or the use of that fragment is completed.